# Testing a Glue record before switching nameservers

Tags: dns-hosting, glue-record

I have a domain like example.com which I have from google domains. I created 2 nameservers and called them dns1.example.com and dns2.example.com. i finished their configuration and opened port 53 on them (22 was already open).
     I then added them as glue records in google domain dns settings page. 
     Now is there a way to test the glue records before switching the nameservers? What I tried is to ssh into the machine using the address dns1.example.com. but that does not work, it is not able to resolve the host. Ssh with IP address works.
      Why is the glue record not able to resolve the host?

I tested it with the command:

```
dig @dns1.example.com example.com
```

I get the error:

```
dig: couldn't get address for 'dns1.example.com': failure
```

If I do

```
dig +norec @h.gtld-servers.net. example.com NS
```

I do get the nameservers listed with the correct IP addresses in the ADDITIONAL SECTION.

Why is not able to get address for dns1.example.com?

Answer (score 0):

A glue record for dns1.example.com will not be used in normal name resolution.

You test by `dig`ging for the NS RRs for the domain and the glue records will appear in the "ADDITIONAL SECTION" of the response. For example:

```
$ dig NS google.com @g.gtld-servers.net
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> NS google.com @g.gtld-servers.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7732
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 9
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns2.google.com.     172800  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:34::a
ns2.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.34.10
ns1.google.com.     172800  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:32::a
ns1.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.32.10
ns3.google.com.     172800  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:36::a
ns3.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.     172800  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:38::a
ns4.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.38.10
```

Comment: Do we need to switch the nameservers for this to show up?

Comment: Yes, you will need to switch nameservers first. The glue records don't exist in example.com. They exist in .com (and gtld?) name servers.

Comment: To answer: "Why is not able to get address for dns1.example.com?" Glue records do not appear in the ANSWER section, ever. (Also, they do not belong to the authoritative zone data.) You will need to add an A record for dns1.example.com in the normal configuration of the zone.

Comment: @MarkWagner glue records do exist in any TLD, this is not specific to any single TLD, it is how to break the DNS resolution problem if your domain is using only in-bailiwick nameservers.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I said glue records exist in com nameservers for example.com (and thus likewise for any other TLDs). Alas by GTLD in my comment I meant root nameservers since I received glue for google.com nameservers  from the root nameservers I checked. I don't understand the point you are trying to make.

Comment: You were saying "they exist in .com (and gtld?)" I parsed the question mark as you not being sure if the behavior is specific to .com or any gTLD, which was the point I answered. As for "I received glue for google.com nameservers from the root nameservers I checked." that is certainly NOT the case. Root nameservers will at most give you only glues for TLD nameservers, not for anything deeper below. Of course I hope that you are not using "root nameservers" to says ".com root nameservers".

Answer (score 0):

An online checking tool such as Zonemaster is able to test a non delegated zone. You specify the zone and the nameservers you wish to test, including with their IPs if needed, which is exactly your case.

Go try it at https://zonemaster.net/, select "Options" and then enter the specific nameservers to be tested (otherwise the normal delegation rules apply). Explanations are given in their FAQ at https://zonemaster.net/en/faq#q12

In the same way you can use https://www.dnsviz.net/ and go to Analyze options before starting the test, and input the specific authoritative nameservers you want to query.

As for

> Why is not able to get address for dns1.example.com?

this is because glue records are inserted only if needed.

Let us imagine `example.com` is served for now by `dns1.example.org` and `dns2.example.org`.  There is no glue records in `.com` authoritative nameserfvers because your domain does not use in-bailiwick nameservers.
If you have a `dns1.example.com` entry, you should get a result for it if your query either `dns1.example.org` or `dns2.example.org` but not if you query any of the `.com` authoritative nameservers

Now, as soon as you change your authoritative nameservers, and `example.com` becomes handled by `dns1.example.com` and `dns2.example.com`, then and only then the authoritative nameservers for `.com` will start supplying a glue for the two names because otherwise resolution would never happen properly.
But before you switch nameservers the glue is not needed.

Comment: The link is dead. I couldn't find an alternative on the site.

Comment: @SamSirry Go to main page, and enable "Options". There you can specify nameservers to use. I edited my answer and added DNSViz where you can do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you; very kind of you to fix the answer.